# Is it possible to run Windows Form Code from c# Class Library without launching the form application?

Tags: c#, winforms, class-library

*I have a class library project in C# where some code doesn't work due to some file access issues. But same code works in windows form application. Is it possible to call windows form application from class library without launching it? Somehow windows form application could run in background? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks*

Comment: Can you add the code that is causing the problem?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to call windows form application from class library without launching it?

Yes.  It's just an assembly; you can load it and use its types.  But then it would have the same behavior, and the same "file access issues" that your other code has.